# How to insert a delimiter while parsing a class with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, selenium, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I'm using Nokogiri and Selenium Webdriver to parse the full contents of a class on a web page:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "nokogiri"
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
browser.get "https://jsfiddle.net"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.page_source)
puts doc.xpath(".//*[@class='aiButton']").inner_text
```

There are elements with class `aiButton`, containing text like "Run", "Save", "Update", etc. This is the result in my terminal:

```
> RunSaveUpdateForkTidyCollaborateSign in
```

Is there a way I can print the contents but include a delimiter, like a space or comma or something, between the elements? My preferred output would be:

```
> Run Save Update Fork Tidy Collaborate Sign in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `join` like so:

```
doc.css('.aiButton').map(&:text).join(' ')
```